# A recursion for the total number of 1's in binary expansions of the first natural numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, digits

Let $$a(n)=a(2^k-n)+k(n-2^{k-1})$$ for  $$1 \leqslant {2^{k - 1}} < n \leqslant {2^k}$$ 
with initial values $a(0)=0, a(1)=0, a(2)=1.$

The first values are $0,0,1,2,4,5,7,9,12,13,15,\dots.$

Comparing with OEIS A000788 it seems that $a(n+1)$ is the total number of $1'$s in binary expansions of ${0,1,\dots,n}.$

Any idea how to prove this?

Comment: Let me take the definition of A000788 as the definition, and try to prove your recurrence relation. Clearly, $a\left(n\right) = a\left(2^k-1\right) - q$, where $q$ is the total number of $1$s in the binary expansions of $n+1, n+2, \ldots, 2^k-1$. But the $1$s in the binary expansions of $n+1, n+2, \ldots, 2^k-1$ (which all have $k$ digits) are in bijection with the $0$s in the $k$-digit binary expansions of $1, 2, \ldots, 2^k-n$, and thus their number is $q = \left(2^k-n\right) k - a\left(2^k-n\right)$. Now, ...

Comment: ... a simple combinatorial argument shows that $q = k 2^{k-1}$ (since each position has a $1$ in exactly $2^{k-1}$ of the numbers $0, 1, \ldots, 2^k-1$). Thus, my first equation becomes $a \left( n \right) = \underbrace{a\left(2^k-1\right)}_{=k2^{k-1}} - \underbrace{q}_{= \left(2^k-n\right) k - a\left(2^k-n\right)} = k 2^{k-1} - \left( \left(2^k-n\right) k - a\left(2^k-n\right) \right) $ $= a \left( 2^k - n \right) + k \left(n - 2^{k-1}\right)$.

Comment: This is a nice proof.